# Some Error about Flink 1.11 source code import to IDEA

Tags: apache-flink

I import Flink 1.11 source code to IDEA.I use Maven3.6.3 and scala2.12. But after Maven resolves dependencies. There are 7 error...I can't know why...

```
Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-dist_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-kafka-test-base_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-kafka011-test_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming-state-machine_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-kafka-test_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-examples-streaming-twitter_2.12:1.11.0

Cannot resolve org.apache.flink:flink-streaming-kafka010-test_2.12:1.11.0
```

Comment: can you attach your pom.xml?

Comment: If you are trying to build Flink itself, have you followed https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.11/flinkDev/ide_setup.html ?

Comment: @ShemTov Thank you ,I don't change anything in pom.xml.... But I add ```-Drat.skip=true ``` in mvn, The build succeed.

Comment: @DavidAnderson I followed this...